# Is there any spin group $Spin(n)$ for any value of $n$ which is isomorphic to $SU(3)$?

Tags: lie-groups, group-isomorphism, spin-geometry

I was wondering about the spin group and its relations with the unitary groups.
Like we have $Spin(2)\simeq U(1)$, $Spin(3) \simeq SU(2)$.

I was wondering whether this relation can be taken further to $SU(3)$.

The motivation behind this, is that, the unitary group in these cases are all important in physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of $SU(n)$ is $n^2-1$. While $\dim(Spin(m))=\dim(SO(m))=m(m-1)/2$. So we get $n^2-1=m(m-1)/2$.

Substituting $n=3$, we get $8=m(m-1)/2$

Solving we get $m=(1\pm \sqrt{65})/2\not\in\mathbb Q$

A contradiction.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It looks like the OP meant "isomorphic as Lie Groups" although that might have been made clearer (e.g. did not mean "homotopy type").  The dimensional argument shows they can't be homeomorphic as topological manifolds which means they can't be isomorphic as Lie groups, unless I missed something here.  Downvoting an answer without providing a comment as to why is not a good practice IMO unless there is an obvious flaw.

Comment: @AlgTop1854  You guessed it right!. i was thinking only in terms of Lie groups, which are  the groups appear in physics. Sorry if my question was ambiguous.

Comment: @Galoisgroup, your calculation seems fine to me, and I think the conclusion is there isn't such a spin group which is ismorphic(as lie groups) to $SU(3)$